# Remove rows with same column value

Tags: php, mysql, unique, distinct

I'm querying a bunch of cities from a zip-code table. I'd only like to grab results with an unique 'City'. (Lots of cities have multiple zips.) How could this be done?

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, 
             ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * 
             cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) +
             sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance 
             FROM Zips HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18",
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);
```

Comment: ur distance calculation by mySQL is too complex , better to use equvalent php function like `deg2rad()`, `sin()`, `cos()`,`acos()` etc...

Comment: Why aren't you using MySQL's **Spatial extension** dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: did u try `(3959 * acos( cos( radians(%f) ) * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * 
             cos( radians( Long ) - radians(%f) ) +
             sin( radians(%f) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `HAVING` at a wrong place `WHERE` is needed here and use `GROUP BY` to group result by city

```
 $query = sprintf("SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos(
 radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin(
 radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips WHERE distance < '%s'  
 GROUP BY City ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18",
```

**EDIT**

You could also try

```
     $query = sprintf("SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos(
     radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin(
     radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips HAVING distance < '%s'  
     GROUP BY City  ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18";
```

OR

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos(
     radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin(
     radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips HAVING distance < '%s'  
     ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18 ) as result_set GROUP BY City";
```

Comment: Won't you need to group by all the non-aggregate columns?

Comment: @Jeffrey: _breaks_ means unexpected result or any syntax error?

Comment: Invalid query: Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause' Whole query: SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips where distance < '50' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
SELECT DISTINCT(city)
```

OR

```
GROUP BY (City)
```

Comment: not possible, if u do distinct city then obviously same name of city will never returned

Comment: actually, distinct(city) still returned multiple rows. the group by returned an error

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by `City`' at line 1

Comment: Order is important.  `GROUP BY` must appear before `HAVING` (I use "GHO(st)" to help me remember the order of the clauses (**G**roup, **H**aving, **O**rder)).

Comment: i remember in alphabetic order :)